# KVM inside Docker inside Hyper-V

Tags: docker, hyper-v, kvm-virtualization

The use case is a Cuckoo sandbox, which is a way to test malware in an isolated environment. Cuckoo is running in a Docker container in a Ubuntu VM, which is in turn managed by Hyper-V.

Inside this Docker container, Cuckoo creates new Windows VMs using KVM "on the fly". It doesn't work.

When trying to manually start a Windows VM using this KVM inside a Docker container (using virsh start win7vm), these errors are displayed inside the Docker container:

```
> root@0a25149f706c:/var/log/libvirt# cat libvirtd.log 2019-11-05
> 10:54:56.137+0000: 5201: info : libvirt version: 4.0.0, package:
> 1ubuntu8.13 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com>
> Wed, 21 Aug 2019 11:08:                           29 +0200) 2019-11-05
> 10:54:56.137+0000: 5201: info : hostname: 634d767f325e 2019-11-05
> 10:54:56.137+0000: 5201: error : virDBusGetSystemBus:109 : internal
> error: Unable to get DBus system bus connection: Failed to connect to
> socket /var/run/d                           bus/system_bus_socket: No
> such file or directory 2019-11-05 10:54:56.137+0000: 5201: error :
> dnsmasqCapsRefreshInternal:741 : Cannot check dnsmasq binary
> /usr/sbin/dnsmasq: No such file or directory 2019-11-05
> 10:54:56.210+0000: 5201: error : virFirewallValidateBackend:193 :
> direct firewall backend requested, but /sbin/ebtables is not
> available: No such file or d                           irectory
> 2019-11-05 10:54:56.210+0000: 5201: error : virFirewallApply:916 :
> internal error: Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend
> 2019-11-05 10:54:57.768+0000: 5201: error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 :
> internal error: Failed to find path for dmidecode binary 2019-11-05
> 10:54:57.768+0000: 5201: error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 : internal
> error: Failed to find path for dmidecode binary 2019-11-05
> 10:54:57.780+0000: 5201: error : virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 :
> internal error: Cannot probe for supported suspend types 2019-11-05
> 10:54:57.780+0000: 5201: warning : virQEMUCapsInit:1224 : Failed to
> get host power management capabilities 2019-11-05 10:54:59.525+0000:
> 5201: error : virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 : internal error:
> Cannot probe for supported suspend types 2019-11-05 10:54:59.525+0000:
> 5201: warning : umlCapsInit:76 : Failed to get host power management
> capabilities 2019-11-05 10:54:59.525+0000: 5201: error :
> virNetDevBridgeCreate:484 : error creating bridge interface virbr0:
> Operation not permitted 2019-11-08 13:19:45.472+0000: 59: info :
> libvirt version: 4.0.0, package: 1ubuntu8.13 (Christian Ehrhardt
> <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com> Wed, 21 Aug 2019 11:08:29          
> +0200) 2019-11-08 13:19:45.472+0000: 59: info : hostname: 0a25149f706c 2019-11-08 13:19:45.472+0000: 59: error :
> dnsmasqCapsRefreshInternal:741 : Cannot check dnsmasq binary
> /usr/sbin/dnsmasq: No such file or directory 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.476+0000: 59: error : virFirewallValidateBackend:193 : direct
> firewall backend requested, but /sbin/ebtables is not available: No
> such file or dir                           ectory 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.476+0000: 59: error : virFirewallApply:916 : internal error:
> Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.478+0000: 59: error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 : internal
> error: Failed to find path for dmidecode binary 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.478+0000: 59: error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 : internal
> error: Failed to find path for dmidecode binary 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.490+0000: 59: error : virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 :
> internal error: Cannot probe for supported suspend types 2019-11-08
> 13:19:45.490+0000: 59: warning : virQEMUCapsInit:1224 : Failed to get
> host power management capabilities 2019-11-08 13:19:48.331+0000: 59:
> error : virSysinfoReadX86:1032 : internal error: Failed to find path
> for dmidecode binary 2019-11-08 13:19:48.770+0000: 59: error :
> virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 : internal error: Cannot probe for
> supported suspend types 2019-11-08 13:19:48.770+0000: 59: warning :
> virLXCDriverCapsInit:90 : Failed to get host power management
> capabilities 2019-11-08 13:19:48.772+0000: 59: error :
> virNodeSuspendSupportsTarget:336 : internal error: Cannot probe for
> supported suspend types 2019-11-08 13:19:48.772+0000: 59: warning :
> umlCapsInit:76 : Failed to get host power management capabilities
> 2019-11-08 13:19:48.774+0000: 59: error : virFirewallApply:916 :
> internal error: Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend
```

Comment: please modify your question and provide more details. docker image used. docker run command with all options. qemukvm command with full options. also some context on what your want to achieve is welcome.

Comment: You are aware that Hyper-V does not expose virtiualation for nesting EXCEPT in VERY VERY VERY specific instances?

Comment: Not aware of that, but I'm in a situation where I don't have much choice: our sysadmin only offers Hyper-V and the software I have to install only supports KVM